# How to update DLL in automation anywhere using metabot

Tags: dll, rpa, automationanywhere

How to update DLL in automation anywhere using metabot. When i am replacing old DLL with updated one its not working. metabot still using old DLL.

i have tried to replace old dll with new one but not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to delete the old DLL from the metabot and then add the new one.

Double check that the new DLL is actually a new version, for example if you have a C# project go to that project, rebuild it and then go to bin -> Debug | Release -> select the new DLL from here

I never had issues with that doing these steps.

Comment: but then i have to map again all metabot variables with DLL.

Comment: If you have updated already existed logic, then you have also to recreate a Mbot logic. If you are just extending Mbot with new functions then you have only to add new logcis.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to delete the DLL as the currently accepted answer states.

All I did was:

1. Open the MetaBot Designer
2. Click Add DLL
3. Choose the updated DLL
4. You are prompted to replace the existing DLL, "A .NET API DLL with the same name already exists in this metabot. Do you want to replace it?". Choose Yes.

At this point the DLL is updated and the existing logic and variables are intact. If you changed one of the existing APIs, you will need to update the corresponding logic, etc.